# Finding if two numbers have the same digit and then remove them from in the original number in Haskell

Tags: haskell, fractions

I am doing [project euler question 33](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=33) and have divised a refactor to solve it but I can't think of how to remove the digit if it is the same across both `x` and `y`.
I got this far:

```
import Ratio
import List
p33 =  [ (x%y) | y <- [10..99] , x <- [10..y], (x `rem` 10) /= 0 , (y `rem` 10) /= 0 , x /= y , (length $ nub $ concat $ map decToList [x,y]) == 3 , [numerator(x%y),denominator(x%y)] == WHAT GOES HERE? ]
```

The cancelling of 0's is not allowed.
What it should do is:

```
49/98 {cancel the 9's}
```

to get:

4/8 as the result. But I can't think of how to remove the common digits from each number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let `x` and `y` be the two numbers. Then one can remove the digits in `x` which it has in common with `y` like this:

```
Prelude> import Data.List
Prelude Data.List> let x = 68
Prelude Data.List> let y = 76
Prelude Data.List> read (show x \\ show y) :: Int
8
```

Flip `x` and `y` to remove digits from `y`. This uses `xs`[`Data.List.(\\)`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3A%5C%5C)`ys`, which removes the *first* occurrence of each element in `ys` from `xs`.

---

**Edit:** you may have solved [problem 33](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=33) by now. If not, let me give you some more hints:

The code which I gave above, i.e. `read (show x \\ show y)` is not really suitable for this problem. What happens if `x` equals *ab* and `y` equals *ba*, for some digits *a* and *b*?

The solution to this problem *can* be written as a single list comprehension. You may want to use [`Data.List.intersect`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3Aintersect) and [`Data.List.nub`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3Anub) to create the following term in your list comprehension:

```
s <- nub $ intersect (show x) (show y)
```

Now `s` ranges over the digits that `x` and `y` have in common. You can remove these from `x` and `y` using

```
map (read . delete s . show) [x, y]
```

I cannot be more explicit without solving the exercise for you, but I'll leave you with two more hints:

- In your code you write `y <- [10..99], x <- [10..y], x /= y`. Observe that this can be written more succinctly as `y <- [10..99], x <- [10..y-1]`.
- Have a look at [`Data.Ratio`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Ratio.html), which provides an easy way to test the equality of rational numbers and automatically calculates the numerator and denominator of a fraction in its reduced form.

Comment: @Jonno: what's your current status? If you update your question with the code you currently have, then I may be able to give you some further pointers.